# sphinx latexpdf: chapter number only for 3 levels

Tags: latex, python-sphinx

the pdf produced by sphinx show prefix numbers only for 3 levels. You can check my snapshot.

[image]

I want there is a `2.1.1.1` before `test2`. Is there any solution? I have set `\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
```

in `latex_preamble` in `conf.py`:

```py
latex_preamble = r"""
% ...

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

% ...
"""
```